# If statement not working for text field

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to make a if statement to check if anything has been enter into a field. If nothing has then the field dose not show here is the code.

```
<?php if(class_exists( 'guys') && meta('guys')?> <option value="<?php meta('guys'); ?>">GUYS</option><?php endif; ?>
```

This part is what displays the text for the field and is what i need to check.

```
<?php meta('guys'); ?>
```

Comment: You are missing a closing `)` and `:` after `&& meta('guys')` Should be `&& meta('guys')):`

Comment: Also maybe a `:` after the if clause... ?

Comment: <?php if ( class_exists('guys') && meta('guys') ) : ?>

Answer (score 2):

You need both the ) and a : in the if and you need to echo the value, like this

```
<?php if(class_exists( 'guys') && meta('guys')) :?> 
    <option value="<?php echo meta('guys'); ?>">GUYS</option>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: After testing a little more. it makes it disappear when nothing is entered but dose not show when you do enter something any ideas ?